# Unity3D How to make object go away form mouse click position 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im thinking about it two days. I still did not made any progress.
I wonder how to do that objects fly away from mouse click position in 2D view?

I tried like that:

```
        pos = Input.mousePosition;
        Vector3 realWorldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(pos);
        print("MOuse pos: " + realWorldPos);

        //print(realWorldPos);
        Vector3 velo = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity;

        if (realWorldPos.x < 0.5)
        {
            velo = new Vector3((realWorldPos.x * speed), velo.y);
        }
        else if(realWorldPos.x > 0.5)
        {
            velo = new Vector3((realWorldPos.x * speed) * (-1), velo.y);
        }
        if (realWorldPos.y < 0.5)
        {
            velo = new Vector3(velo.x, realWorldPos.y * speed);
        }
        else if (realWorldPos.y > 0.5)
        {
            velo = new Vector3(velo.x, (realWorldPos.y * speed) * (-1));
        }

        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = velo;
```

But it doesnt work as I want.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Are those objects moving or  not? Also, what is your script attached to? The single objects? Is there a range the click has to be in for this to happen? Is there a reason for doing this in viewport space, not world space?

Comment: There is object PLAYER, CAMERA following player with SmoothCamera2D script, and click function tried to do in PLAYER object because I didnt have another idea.
Ofc there is no must be any range. I did use viewport space because i didnt know how to do velocity in world space when i get ex. -305, 3506 positions, its much easier in 0-1, 0-1 positions.

Comment: But the objects that should fly away are not the player? Shall the player push them away or should it actually be the point you click (and I assume the player sould move to)? Again, is there a range limit on that push effect in relation to the mouse position?

Comment: That part about range is a yes and a no to me. For pushing away I would say use `AddForce`. Currently you are changing the velocity of the player (that is what `GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>()` will give you). You just need a directional vector (which you can normalize) and put a factor (=push-strength) in there. The tricky part is getting the other objects.

Comment: The object that may fly away is PLAYER. Depend where player click there PLAYER go away from this click doesnt matter how far away from PLAYER were clicks.

My first attempt was with AddForce but I just dont know how to get X,Y where the object should move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this to work your `Rigidbody2D` must have `Gravity Scale` set to 0.

This is a simple test code that works for me, is placed on a sprite object:

```
public class PushPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float pushPower = 50.0f;

    Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Vector3 dir = transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            dir = dir.normalized;

            rb.AddForce(dir * pushPower, ForceMode2D.Force);

            // as alternative:
            rb.velocity = dir * pushPower;
        }
    }
}
```

You need to adjust the values a bit, also in the regidbody (like drag) to get it the way you want.

Edit:

`transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition)`: calculate the directional vector from the mouse position to the player position (have a look a vector algebra if you are not familiar with this) which is the direction away from the click (in a straight line).

`dir.normalized`: this shortens the vector to a length (= magnitude) of `1` (again have a look at vectors) so it really is just a direction. You could omit this and reduce the factor, but doing it this way your factor equals the force you use.

Comment: It works!
Can you explain me why do you substract camera from position and what is normalized? What this exactly do?

Comment: @xqz in vector math if you want to get the DIRECTION from A to B .. it is simply "B minus A".  So that's what Gunnar's excellent code is doing there.

Comment: @xqz like Joe Blow said. I've put some info at the bottom of the answer for that.